# SVN info shows old Revision # as the Current Revision

Tags: linux, centos, svn

I have an SVN repo. When I recently committed a change, the reflected current revision # is 620:

```
Transmitting file data ...
Committed revision 620.
```

However, if I then run`svn info` I get the following:

```
Path: .
URL: http://www.site.com.testing/repos/site.com/trunk
Repository Root: http://svn.server/repos/site.com
Repository UUID: a9c3a166-39f6-4cfb-8622-fd24eb11034b
Revision: 584
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: bob
Last Changed Rev: 584
Last Changed Date: 2012-03-26 18:32:55 -0400 (Mon, 26 Mar 2012)
```

So committing something tells me that the current SVN repo is 620 but `svn info` tells me that the current rev is 584. Also `svn log` shows 584 as the current (most recent) rev as well.

If I look at the SVN Log via TortoiseSVN in Windows it correctly shows revision 620 as the current revision.

Am I missing something regarding how `svn info` and `svn log` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Likely the svninfo command is showing you the revision of the current working directory, whereas when you commit a changed file or files, then the output of that commit shows the new revision of those files.  584 will be the last changed/updated revision of the folder.

Try running an `svn update` on the folder and the re-running `svn info`. It should bring the rest of the folder up to 620

Answer (score 9):

What Subversion is showing you is that you've checked out revision 584. The information is taken directly from the `.svn/entries` file, and not from the server.

This stems from Subversion's basic design of not requesting information from the repository server whenever possible. It was a decision made to allow users to have a lot of Subversion's power if they happen to be working remotely and have no network connection to the repository server.

- If you do a `svn info` on one of the files just committed, you'll see that file is at revision 620.
- If you did a `svn info http://www.site.com.testing/repos/site.com/trunk`, you'll see the last revision was revision 620 because it is talking to the server.
- If you did a `svn update` and then a `svn info`, you'll see your working directory is at revision 620.

Just a quick question: Did you commit a few files, or did you commit the entire working directory? If you specified in your commit the files that were changed, this would make sense. Subversion wouldn't have known to update the `.svn/entries` file in the root of your working directory. However, I've seen this even when I commit all changes. I've taken to doing an svn up whenever I commit all of my changes.

Remember: *It's not a bug. It's a feature.*

Comment: Yeah I committed just one file in a sub-directory somewhere. Not the root folder. I know it's not a bug. It makes sense to me know. Also I didn't know I could `svn info` the repo's trunk itself, so +1 for that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I thought I was going nuts.    I know this is an old post - but I just stumbled across this "feature" today while writing a build/packaging script.  After coding/committing locally I wanted to build the package using my local code, but the version number was the Previous one.  While performing "update" fixes it - that assumes I want to update ALL files too - which may not be what I want to do when creating Beta packages from my local dev PC.  That's my problem - not yours :-)